# How come my Tuple is printing multiple times?

Tags: python, tuples

I’m working on an exercise involving tuples in Python Crash course. I just want the tuple to print once using the ‘for’ loop, but it keeps printing 5 times instead.

```
buffet = ('pizza', 'taco', 'egg', 'rice', 'blt')
for items in buffet:  
  print(buffet)
```

Output:

```
('pizza', 'taco', 'egg', 'rice', 'blt')
('pizza', 'taco', 'egg', 'rice', 'blt') 
('pizza', 'taco', 'egg', 'rice', 'blt')
('pizza', 'taco', 'egg', 'rice', 'blt')
('pizza', 'taco', 'egg', 'rice', 'blt')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`buffet` is the tuple itself. You will print it n (items in your tuple) times with your current implementation.

This should give you the expected output:

```py
buffet = ('pizza', 'taco', 'egg', 'rice', 'blt')
for item in buffet:  
    print(item)
```